# Why do I get an InvalidCastException when reading values from OdbcDataReader after checking for null values?

Tags: c#, exception, null, odbc

Using OdbcDataReader in C#, I have a query that returns an integer column which could contain nulls.

For each row, I want to test whether the value is null and handle it appropriately. However, when I do this using IsDBNull I get an InvalidCastException even for rows that are not null. Why does this occur?

If I leave out the IsDBNull check, I get an error only for rows that contain nulls.

```
OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=...");
DbConnection.Open();
OdbcCommand DbCommand = DbConnection.CreateCommand();
DbCommand.CommandText = @"
                        select 1 as result from dual
                        union
                        select null as result from dual";
OdbcDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();
Int32 result;
while (DbReader.Read())
{
    if (!DbReader.IsDBNull(0))
    {
        result = DbReader.GetInt32(0);  // Results in InvalidCastException
    }
    else
    {
        result = 0;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(result));
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Edit:

The following technique to check for nulls seems to work. I would like to know why the above does not though.

```
object resultObject = DbReader.GetValue(0);
if (resultObject != DBNull.Value)
{
    result = Convert.ToInt32(resultObject);
}
else
{
    result = 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the exact message of this exception?

Comment: What kind of type do u get while debugging?
DbReader.GetSqlValue(0).GetType()

Comment: System.InvalidCastException was unhandled

Message=Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: or DbReader.GetFieldType(0) like Roy Google said.. not sure which one works on OdbcDataReader

Comment: In your working technique edit, you changed **two** things. You can't infer anything from this about the null check. Only change the null check or the way you get the value, not both.

Comment: correct - OdbcDataReader does not have GetSqlValue()

Comment: Thanks - it looks like it is coming back as a Decimal. That's odd because the column in the database is defined as integer.

Comment: Why does "result = DbReader.GetInt32(0);" work when I leave out the IsDBNull check? (even though the field type is still coming back as Decimal)

Comment: @WarrenBlumenow what type of database are you connecting to with ODBC? It'll be the ODBC Driver that's inferring the data type

Comment: It's Oracle. I am happy to force a conversion to integer - solves my immediate problem. Just a bit mystified why GetInt32 works on a Decimal value when I don't check for IsDBNull but does not work when I do the check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's most likely happening because the value is not of Int32 type.

You can work out the field type with `DbReader.GetFieldType(0);`

Or you can handle it by converting it to an Int32 with `Convert.ToInt32(DbReader.GetValue(0));`